Proving triangle midsegment theorem without quadrilaterals or similarity
I'm here with a question on a basic fact presented to you below:

The midline of a triangle is parallel to the third side of that triangle and half its length.

There is a known proof listed here on ProofWiki, but I'm looking for something a bit closer to axioms.
I would like an alternative proof based on Euclidean axioms, that does not involve circles, quadrilaterals, or similarity: only triangle congruence and properties of angles formed by parallel lines and a transversal. I think this should absolutely be possible (it's always possible to bisect the third side of the triangle, thus getting the segment of the same length as the midline is, according to the theorem).
What is the elementary proof with these criteria?

Well, just redo the original proof of the similar triangle properties.  It's a direct application so replicating the proof follows.  Indeed I think it is the only way to do it without relying on the basic theorem it follows directly from, is to reprove the theorem of which it is a direct application.

Euclid VI.2 is the original proof of this statement, which arises naturally once ratios are established. However, we can derive it like this:
Given $\triangle{ABC}$, mark the midpoint $D$ of $AB$ and construct $DE$ parallel to $BC$ where $E$ is the intersection with $CA$. Cut $BF$=$DE$ from $BC$. By SAS, $\triangle{ADE} \cong \triangle{DBF}$. Since $DE \parallel BC$, $\angle{EDF}=\angle{DFB}$ and then again by SAS $\triangle{ADE} \cong \triangle{FED}$. Note that at this point, with equal interior angles, we have all the internal segments $DE,EF,DF$ parallel to the respective sides of $BC,AB,AC$, so $\angle{ADE}=\angle{EFC}$ and $\angle{DAE}=\angle{FEC}$. Finally, by ASA $\triangle{ADE} \cong \triangle{EFC}$.
Thus, $\triangle{ADE} \cong \triangle{DBF} \cong \triangle{EFC}$, and a line constructed from the midpoint of one side, parallel to the base, will terminate at the midpoint of the other side. Moreover, since $DE=BF=FC$, the midsegment $DE$ is half the length of the base $BC$. A proof by contradiction can prove the reverse direction where you join midpoints and need to prove $DE \parallel BC$.


The curious part is, well, ... how does that prove that $DE = \frac{1}{2}BC$?

@Rusurano, see the final 3-way congruence I highlighted.
